# Can we have an RSS feed for the /review page?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, feed

This came up in the mod chat earlier today. Would it be possible to add RSS feed support for the /review page?

---

This makes zero sense now that /review has been completely redone, and the jury's out on whether or not this ever made sense. So I get to status-decline my own request. :)

Comment: +1 For mods who are effectively using the present RSS feeds to review, this would save a trip to `/review` and ensure that `/review` accurately reflects content that has been reviewed.

Answer (score 7):

Don't most RSS readers pull the feed and save all the entries in it until the user gets around to reading them? It seems like that would be really annoying; by the time you checked your RSS feeds and went through all the /review posts, half of them could already be deleted or otherwise taken care of

Comment: I'm the one who mentioned it. Many RSS readers are very configurable. At the very least, one can look at the top ones and the check "okay mark all read."

Comment: @mattdm They are, but if you configure your RSS reader to not save entries and just pull the data from /review live, then what's the point? You're not using a "feed" anymore, you might as well just go to /review directly

Comment: The feed can then be easily pushed places. Specifically, they can become (background) alerts on my phone.

Comment: Came here with the same question and didn't expect this answer, nice Job @MichaelMrozek