# RSS feed for flags and review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderator-tools, feed

Is there a way to get a RSS feed for flags and the review queue? If not, this is a feature request.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can we have an RSS feed for the /review page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87206/229699)

Comment: By flags, you mean the status of your own personal flags, or flags visible in the 10k tools?

Comment: @BradLarson The moderator tools.

Comment: Looks like the other question doesn't cover the mod tools, so if you change your question to just be those it shouldn't be a dupe. At least not of that question.

Comment: Flags are very restricted. Your flags can only be seen by you, and the 10k tools obviously require 10,000 reputation. I doubt they will *ever* make that information publicly accessible via an RSS feed.

Comment: @animuson Good point. Hadn't thought of that.