# Community post Low Quality and First Post questions into chat?

Tags: feature-request, review, chat

Is there either an existing way or could we get a way to have Community automatically send First Posts and Low Quality Posts into our chat so they get reviewed and taken care of quicker?

Comment: There's a chat feed you can set up. Unless you mean the reviews, I don't see how a bot can decide whether a post is VLQ or not. (Not the downvoter, BTW)

Comment: @M.A.R. could you please post that (including how to setup / link to how to setup) the chatfeed you're talking about as an answer

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to build your own feed, as the review [has no feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87206/can-we-have-an-rss-feed-for-the-review-page) of its own. /cc @M.A.R.